# OmniAuth facebook with Devise in Ruby on rails not passing app_id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, omniauth, omniauth-facebook

I am setting up a rails application (4.1.10) using Devise. I am adding the OmniAuth Facebook integration using this devise guide : https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/OmniAuth:-Overview

I think I have set up everything that I should ( I am aware I should put the app_id and secret into ENV variables - which I will move onto once this works) However when I click my sign into facebook link I get an error:

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=&display=popup&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.clazzoo.com%2Fusers%2Fauth%2Ffacebook%2Fcallback&response_type=code&scope=email%2Cuser_birthday%2Cread_stream&state=b43008b5d8e714e91ac37b4410f7758655efecbca7bfe98e

Warning
The parameter app_id is required
```

The config is here:

```
    # Use this hook to configure devise mailer, warden hooks and so forth.
    # Many of these configuration options can be set straight in your model.
    Devise.setup do |config|
     ...
    ...

    config.omniauth :facebook, "1602932433319776", "7221cf917c6e55ba68c8e81145994481",
      :scope => 'email,user_birthday,read_stream',
      :display => 'popup'

    config.omniauth :stripe_connect,
    Settings.stripeConnectClientID,
    Settings.stripeSecretKey,
    :scope => 'read_write',
    :stripe_landing => 'register'
  end
```

The User model has the omniauthable set:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :confirmable,
         :omniauthable, :omniauth_providers => [:facebook]
```

So why when I click my link does it miss out the appropriate ID?

Comment: Did you add your ***ENV varaibles*** to `~/.bashrc`?

Comment: I am not using the ENV variables in this test when I am developing - they are hard coded...as per the code example in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what was broken - turns out recommiting my code to heroku and doing a heroku restart fixed it. Simples ;)

Comment: just like that? I am getting the same error, although all the variables are hard coded

Comment: Yeah thats all there was to it....I no longer use Heroku so can't help you further!